# Notification on Iphone when application is killed from the background

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

I am developing an iPhone App in which there is a server which sends the push notification, that notification is just to intimate that the new message is arrived.

The notification that is coming from the server is sampled below :

> {"last_updated":"2015-04-07:15:00:00","aps":{"badge":2,"alert":{"action-loc-key":"Open","body":"New Message"},"content-available":1}}

I can pull the exact message from the server, if application is running in background and then I show the local notification with the exact message.

But if the application is not running in background then the notification that is coming from the server is shown.

How can I handle this scenario ?

Comment: @Jitendra Gandhi
Do you know the answer of this question?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not running, iOS receive the Notification and show it with a badge or alert (depends on your `registerUserNotificationSettings` settings). When the user opens the notification will be redirect to your application.

After that you can handle your notification on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method with a code like the following:

```
//App Launched from Push Notification
NSDictionary *remoteNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if (remoteNotification)
{
    //Handle your notification
    NSLog(@"App Launched from Push Notification");
}
```

Comment: But what if I want the application to get started as soon as I receive the notification, and the application is killed from the background.

Comment: It's not possible, iOS does not allow it, the application can start only with notification interaction by the user. Try to see Background Fetch if it is for your case

Answer (score 0):

Try Interactive push notifications. App will not be launched automatically but you can do small tasks(which can be completed in few milli seconds) with just one click on the notification button.